# How to mount something on very old cedar shake with no available stud underneath

Tags: exterior, mounting

I have a 110-year-old house with possibly original cedar shake siding. It's been painted a LOT during its life and is in good condition.

I'd like to mount an address plaque on it in a location where there is not a stud to find underneath - but its literally the only place I could install it on the front of the house.

The plaque is 9x12 Walnut with a porcelain sign mounted on it. Call it 3.6 pounds.

The wall is too thick to use a molly bolt.

Suggestions on how to mount it would be very welcome.

Comment: You _could_ screw it directly to the shakes. It probably isn't heavy, unless you went for a large solid-brass engraved thing.

Comment: I second the screws but use pilot holes for them.

Comment: If hypothetically the screws fail (they probably won’t), you could use a toggle with an extra long screw.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - it was very helpful!